# Filtering and sorting on a calculated field

Tags: yii

Good day! Such a problem.
There is a `table` with students: StudID, StudSurName, StudLastName, ...
Related table with scores: PointID, PointStudFK (foreign key), Points (points).
Relation Has_many.

```
'points' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Points', array('PointStudFK' => 'StudID'))
```

For each student the amount of points I brought in `CGridView`, but the filters do not work.
The filter works, but compares the value with the sum of all the scores of students, and not for each.

Virtual field

```
private $_point= null;
```

Setter and getter

```
getSumPoints () - function calculating the sum of scores on individual student

    public function getPoint()
    {
        if ($this->_point === null && $this->points!== null)
        {
            $this->_point = $this->points->getSumPoints($this->StudID);
        }
        return $this->_point;
    }
    public function setPoint($value)
    {
        $this->_point = $value;
    }

search()

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->with = array('points'=>array(
    'select' => array('SUM(Points) as total')));
    if(!empty($this->pointExp1)) $criteria->having = "total = {$this->point}";
```

Need to group, but do not know how.

Comment: Yes, you need a GROUP BY, propably on StudID?

Comment: maybe use stat relation, like this: 'pointsSum' => array(self::HAS_STAT, 'Points', array('PointStudFK' => 'StudID')), look [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query)

Comment: Thank you! Helped $criteria->group='points.PointStudFK';